# PHP, read and retrieve data from pdf file in arabic

Tags: php, pdf, phpmyadmin, arabic

I upload pdf file into my database (phpMyAdmin) using PHP. What I want is read data from it and retrieve specific data to represented in my website, but the pdf file in the Arabic language and contain tables is there a way to read and retrieve data that support Arabic?